# Update table1 from table2 (Insert new, update changed only, remove missing)

Tags: sql, sql-update, mariadb, sql-insert, load-data-infile

I see similar question asked a dozen times, but none quite my scenario.

My intent is to have a current table (table1) updated based on csv imported temporary table (table2);

1. Remove missing `appid`s
2. Add new `appid`s
3. Update `name` if it has changed

Additionally there is a 2 triggers for after update *(thanks to which I realized what I was doing and not simply running with broken code)*;

1. log updates in history table (table3)
2. log deletes in history table (table3)

Currently I perform operations as follows:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table2 (
    appid INT,
    name VARCHAR(255)
    );
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "outp.csv" INTO TABLE table2 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';

UPDATE table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.appid = table1.appid
SET table1.name = table2.name;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE table2;
```

---

Currently history table gets every existing row whenever I run the update, plus new rows are not imported and missing rows are not removed.

What would be the correct way to accomplish the the intended update operation?

---

**Edit:** Actually, it made more sense to go with the exact statements provided by **GMB** below. After I realized how the insert statement works, it just makes more sense to avoid having to run a third unnecessary statement since insert will do both insert and update in one.

Old three statement script for reference:

```
DELETE FROM table1
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.appid = table1.appid
    );

UPDATE table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.appid = table1.appid
SET table1.name = table2.name
WHERE table1.name <> table2.name;

INSERT INTO table1 (appid, name)(
    SELECT table2.appid, table2.name FROM table2
    LEFT JOIN table1 ON table2.appid = table1.appid
    WHERE table1.appid IS NULL
    );
```

Comment: Can you simply replace the entire table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in a single statement. Unlike some other databases, MySQL/MariaDB does not provide a fully-featured `merge` statement.

You can, however, perform the operations in two steps: first get rid of "missing" rows in the target, then use `insert ... on duplicate key` to insert/update the new and existing rows:

```
delete from table1 
where not exists(select 1 from table2 where table2.appid = table1.appid)

insert into table1 (appid, name)
select appid, name
from table2
on duplicate key update name = values(name)
```

This assumes, of course, that `id` is the primary key of `table1` (so the `insert` statement can properly identify the duplicates). I would also recommend defining `id` as the primary key of temporary table `table2`: this wil make the queries faster.

Comment: Is it possible to define WHEN statement with 'on duplicate' to avoid unnecessary updates? If not, I found another statement for inserts and updates which I'll add to original post when I settle with best method. But the delete statement seems to run very long (30+minutes). Would it be possible to optimize it somehow?

Comment: @ichihaifu: (1) what is the total size of the table, and how many rows are being deleted? (2) Did you define `id` as primary key of the temporary table as suggested?

Comment: There are 96750 rows currently in table1, and `appid` is the primary key. No keys were deleted on my first test run, but that is because there were (most likely) no keys to be deleted. I could remove a few to simulate a deletion case. -> *EDIT:* I did not yet try setting primary key in temporary table yet.

Comment: Aha, yes. It took less than a second to run deletions once primary key was specified. Thanks.

Comment: Just a final consideration to my question that I edited in to my first comment: *Is it possible to define WHEN statement with 'on duplicate'?* I may want to combine update and inserts in to one statement if it is possible to avoid the unnecessary updates.

Comment: @ichihaifu: no. But if the value of `name` is the same, MySQL does not actually write it.